# Editing flash cookies programmatically

Tags: flash, cookies

For fun, I wanted to mess around with a flash game by editing the save file (flash cookies with .sol file extension).

I have found editors like .minerva to be kinda fun to play with, but now I'd like to edit the .sol file programmatically.

I am looking for help on how I can programmatically edit the flash cookie. Quite frankly, I don't really have the budget to buy Flash just to mess around.

Ideally, if you could refer me to an API for Python that lets me edit flash cookies that would be the best for me.

Next best would be an API in pretty much any modern/popular language (C,C++,Ruby,Java,Haskell,etc.).

And if none of those are available a link to a description of the anatomy of a flash cookie would be really cool. It seems like a fun project to write a Python module to edit flash cookies, if none are readily available.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[s2x](http://osflash.org/s2x) is a python script that can convert .sol files from and to XML.